# Function Call History In Python

Tags: python, function

I have a test suite and trying to enhance it for better debug ability. I need to get the history of function call, return status and the line number at which the function returned. This is to be done without doing a change at each and every function but in one common location which calls the test routines.
I tried using traceback, but it gives the state of current stack only. If I want to know history of the functions called, I would not get using traceback. Any pointers could really be useful Thank you all.

Example:

```
enter code here
def a():
  print "I am in A"
  ret = xyz()
  return ret

def b():
  ret = a()
  print "I am in B"
  return ret

def c():
  print "I am in C"
  return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
  val = b();
  if val == False:
     ==> Print History <==
```

Comment: What do you mean by history ? Please give an example of what you need.

Comment: Say I have following code snippet:

def a():
  print "I am in A"
  ret = xyz()
  return ret

def b():
  ret = a()
  print "I am in B"
  return ret

def c():
  print "I am in C"
  return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
  val = b();
  if val == False:
     ==> Print History <==

Comment: You should edit your question. As such it's unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the [trace module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html).  It will let you see what functions (and even what lines) of a program have been run.